# Correct Way to Migrate from Procedual to OOP PHP - What should be the "Object"?

Tags: php, oop

I'm learning to code as OOP but think I'm not understanding the fundamentals correctly on how to call lots of rows from a database, but then make an object out of each row.

So for example drawing from DB and working through all relevant pupils.

I am currently doing something like this:

```
<?php

    //Class -----------------------
    $pupils = new getPupils();
    $pupils->addFilter('year1');
    $pupil_info = $pupils->returnPupils();

    //On Page ----------------
    foreach($pupil_info as $pupil_id->$p){
        //Show pupil - but this is no longer OOP?
        echo $p['pupil_name'];
    }

?>
```

The problem I have is that I think the 'object' should be the "pupil", not the group of pupils?

But if I got each pupil in a separate object, I'd need to call their information out pupil by pupil rather than in one function.

So should I be doing it like this? (which avoids each object calling the info from db each time)

```
<?php

    function getPupilsInfo($year='*')
    {
        /* Call all pupils from database and return multi-dimensional array */
        return $pupilsInfo;
    }

    //On Page --------------------------------
    $pupilInfo = getPupilsInfo('year1');

    foreach($pupilInfo as $pupil_id->$p)
    {
        $thisPupil = new Pupil($p);
        echo $thisPupil->getPupilName();
    }

?>
```

I suppose my question at what point do I turn it into an object? Maybe drawing pupil info from database needs to be one class, and then working with each pupil is another class?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Like GrenierJ mentioned, it is good practice to make a Collection of Objects for every Kind of Objects that could be exist more than once at one time.

I would build it something like this.Not the exact Solution quist a quick and dirty one to get the direction right :).

```
Pupil {
private $tablename="pupil"
private $name, $prename, $gender etc. (private with getter and setter function)
/**@var SchoolClass *//
private $schoolClass (class is a protected keyword..., this is the backConnection to the collection)

}


SchoolClass {
private classes=new Array();
public function addNewClassToSchool(string $className){
    §this->classes[$className][]=new Array();
}

publlic function addPupilToClass($className, Pupil $pupil){
   $this->classes[$className][]=$pupil
}

public function getSchoolClass($className){
  return $this->classes[$className];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a class that represents a Pupil and also a class that represents a list of a Pupil:

The class Pupil will contain all business logic for a Pupil, ( get name, age, etc).
And the class PupilCollection will contain all business logic for a list of Pupil, ( add, remove, list all pupils, describe them, count, etc). If you don't have the need for specific methods for the collection of Pupil, you do not need to create the PupilCollection class, an array of Pupil will work great.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. 

So if I create "Pupil" and "fetchPupilList" classes, the data for new Pupil will always come from each row returned in new fetchPupilList. - bearing that in mind, should the class "Pupil" be associated in any way to class fetchPupilList?
i.e. should it be extends class or anything like that? (or completely independent)

Again thanks to GrenierJ & bomel2k9 for explanation